# How to adjust the border according to the input group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am working on alpha.dubaiexporters.com.

i almost made the website responsive using bootstrap.
This is what i am trying to design:
[image]

i wanted to adjust the border of the input group according to input group.

[image]

When i am resizing it,it is not touching the input group. how to achieve it? The below is my code:

```css
.searcharea{
    background-image: url('https://d12dkjq56sjcos.cloudfront.net/pub/media/wysiwyg/Dubai-Skyline-Burj-Al-Arab-Big-Bus-Tours-01.17.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /*min-height: 300px;*/
    position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    max-width:100%;
    
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container-fullwidth">       
          <div class="searcharea col-sm-12"> 
             <div class="container">
                             <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
    
    
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                              <div class="input-group" style="padding-top:0px;padding-left:0px;" >
                                   <input id="txtkeyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Keyword" style="display:inline; width:290px;height:60px;" type="text" runat="server" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <input id="txtserach" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" list="browsers" name="myBrowser" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search By Category" style="display:inline; width:290px;height:60px;"/>
                                  <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Automotive"/>
      <option value="Building and Interiors"/>
      <option value="Food, Kitchen and Hotel Supplies"/>
      <option value="Industrial and Machinery"/>
      <option value="Consumer and Household"/>
      <option value="Medical and Healthcare"/>
                         <option value="Printing , Packaging and Plastic"/>
                         <option value="IT / Telecom / Electronics"/>
                         <option value="Oil and Gas"/>
                         <option value="Power and Energy"/>
    </datalist>
                  
                               <button id="btnsearch" runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="height:61px;" onserverclick="btnsearch_Click">
                            Search
                            </button>
       
                           
      </div>
                        </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-2"> </div>
    
                    </div>
                                 
                            </div></form></div>
    
                             </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `outline` property for all inputs and button and it worked.

```
outline: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

now check, `alpha.dubaiexporters.com`

Answer (score 0):

I tried visiting your page for playing with the code but it doesn't seem to help much.

The problem you are facing is the input doesn't include the defined margin and padding parameters.
Visit my to-do page to understand this:
[MYTODO](https://mytodo.netlify.com/)

Here I have used a property called : `box-sizing: border-box` on the Add a new todo input area.

If you disable it in my page, the input tag enlarges and doesn't fit the parent box.

Play around with the box-sizing property and I think you must be good to go.